# How to add breakpoint for all same method calls in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

For example, I want to add breakpoints for all `[super dealloc];` calls. Is there any quick way to add breakpoint for all **same** methods calls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for debug purposes you can create NSObject category and redefine those methods there.

```
@implementation NSObject (debug)
-(void) dealloc {

}
@end
```

The same works with other classes, however it's not guaranteed with iOS ones, cause some internal categories may interfere your ones.

Comment: Max, that's not that simple. NSObject do actually some deallocation in its dealloc method. If you 're-categorize' dealloc method, mostly all allocated space will never be released. That's why you absolutely need  to swizzle dealloc method (+ calling the original after)in order to get the expected behavior

Comment: Yes I know that, and that's why this it just a quick solution for debug purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a quick way to do it, but you can swizzle NSObject dealloc method, and setting a breakpoint on it.